# How to get a number with variable number of digits from a string in a file using bash script?

Tags: bash, substring

I have the following file:

**APP_VERSION.ts**

```
export const APP_VERSION = 1;
```

This is the only content of that file, and the `APP_VERSION` variable will be incremented as needed.

So, the `APP_VERSION` could be a single digit number or multiple digit number, like `15` or `999`, etc.

I need to use that value in one of my bash scripts.

**use-app-version.sh**

```
APP_VERSION=`cat src/constants/APP_VERSION.ts`
echo $APP_VERSION
```

I know I can read it with `cat`. But how can I parse that `string` so I can get exactly the `APP_VERSION` value, whether it's `1` or `999`, for example.

Comment: `export const APP_VERSION = 1` isn't a valid shell variable assignment. There shouldn't be spaces on either side of `=`

Comment: @Inian Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm just getting that as a string value. I don't want to run that assignment on my bash script. I just need to read it as a string using `cat` and I need to split it and get only the `APP_VERSION` value.

Comment: If this is the only text in the whole file, `grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' APP_VERSION.ts` would return just the number.

Comment: @BenjaminW. That is the only text. Very good answer! Works perfectly for my case.

Comment: This question ended up being more specific than I though. But thanks everyone who gave an answer. I'll update the title, since most of the answers are relying on the fact that I was looking for digits on a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -En 's/(^.*APP_VERSION.*)([[:digit:]]+.*)(\;.*$)/\2/p' src/constants/APP_VERSION
```

Using sed, split the line into three sections defined by opening and closing brackets. Substitute the line for second section on ( the version value) and print.

Comment: It works. But it doesn't work if I get rid of the spaces, like `APP_VERSION=1`. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. I've amended the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this awk:

```sh
app_ver=$(awk -F '[[:blank:];=]+' '$(NF-2) == "APP_VERSION" {print $(NF-1)}' src/constants/APP_VERSION.ts)

echo "$app_ver"
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concat some commands to remove everything else:

```
APP_VERSION=`cat src/constants/APP_VERSION.ts | awk -F '=' '{print $2}' | tr -d ' ' | tr -d ';'`
```

1 - Cat get all file content

2 - AWK gets all content after '='

3 - Remove space

4 - Remove ;

Answer (score 1):

A simple

`APP_VERSION=$(grep --text -Eo '[0-9]+' src/constants/APP_VERSION.ts)`

should be enough

Answer (score 1):

With bash only:

```
APP_VERSION=$(cat src/constants/APP_VERSION.ts)
APP_VERSION=${APP_VERSION%;}
APP_VERSION=${APP_VERSION/*= }
```

Line 2 removes the trailing ';', line 3 removes everything before "= ".
Alternatively, you could set APP_VERSION as an array, take 5th element, and remove trailing ';'.

Or, another solution, using IFS:

```
IFS='=;' read a APP_VERSION < src/constants/APP_VERSION.ts
```

In this version, the space will remain before version number.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the task can be rephrased to "extract the digits from a file", there are a few options:

- Delete all characters that aren't digits with `tr`:

  ```sh
  version=$(tr -cd '[:digit:]' < infile)
  ```
- Use grep to match all digits and retain nothing but the match:

  ```sh
  version=$(grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' infile)
  ```
- Read file into string and delete all non-digits with just Bash:

  ```sh
  contents=$(< infile)
  version=${contents//[![:digit:]]}
  ```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use `printf -v ...`, instead of `version="${contents//[![:digit:]]}"` ?

Comment: @Philippe Not really – the other commands print the number, this one stores it in a variable, so at first I thought I could just `echo "${contents//[![:digit:]]}"`, then I thought I'll use `printf` instead, then I thought I can store it in a variable directly with `printf -v` – but if I wanted the result in a variable, I'd just assign it, as you suggest. I'll update, it's also easier to read.